# Wpf listview where listviewitem is a custom button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a problem. I have a list view in my xaml:

```
<ListView 
        Margin="0 10 0 0"
        DockPanel.Dock="Top"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        BorderThickness="0"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:ItemView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

My item view looks like this (which is in UserControl tag):

```
<buttons:MyButton
    cal:Message.Attach="DoSomething">
    <buttons:MyButton.Visual>
        <DockPanel
            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <local:Image 
                DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                CountryCode="{Binding Source}"/>

            <TextBlock 
                DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Padding="15 0 0 0"
                FontFamily="{StaticResource MediumFont}"
                FontSize="16"
                Foreground="{StaticResource DarkText}"
                Text="{Binding TextValue}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </buttons:MyButton.Visual>
</buttons:MyButton>
```

Now the problem is that when i click on the list item, my selectedItem is not set. It always null unless I click on the very edge of the list item, then it sets the selected value, but i have to click again in the middle of the item to call the action I want.

My question is: How can I make my list view item on click (on the whole item plot) set the selected item and call the action I want?

P.S. I am using Caliburn Micro if this helps...

Comment: If code behind is acceptable for you, in the Click handler for the button cast the sender as FrameworkElement, get its DataContext, cast it to your model and assign it to the SelectedItem property in your ViewModel, which luckily is already TwoWay binded

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using code behind or a view model, you could do something like this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
     <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Focusable="False">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ClickCommand, ElementName=ListViewName}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <!-- YOUR TEMPLATE HERE -->
      <Button.Template>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a view/control related thing. You could handle the `Click` event for the `Button` and explicitly set the `IsSelected` property of the parent `ListViewItem` container like this:

```
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var listViewItem = FindParent<ListViewItem>(sender as DependencyObject);
    if (listViewItem != null)
        listViewItem.IsSelected;
}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <local:ItemView ButtonBase.Click="OnClick"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Or you could set the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView` to the `DataContext` of the element:

```
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
    if (fe != null)
        listView.SelectedItem = fe.DataContext;    
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but what I think you were looking for is something like this

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItemTemplates}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel>
                 <Button x:Name="StartPage">
                     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                         <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                             <cal:Action.Target>
                                 <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="StartPage">
                                     <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding}" />
                                 </cal:ActionMessage>
                             </cal:Action.Target>
                         </i:EventTrigger>
                     </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                     <Button.Template>
                         <ControlTemplate>
                             <StackPanel Width="210" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                 <Image Source="{Binding Path=Source}"
                                        Stretch="None" />

                                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                             </StackPanel>
                         </ControlTemplate>
                     </Button.Template>
                 </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView/>
```

Then you can easily bind this with the following

```
private ObservableCollection<ListViewItemTemplate> listViewItemTemplates;

public ObservableCollection<ListViewItemTemplate> ListViewItemTemplates
{
    get => listViewItemTemplates;
    set
    {
        listViewItemTemplates = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ListViewItemTemplates");
    }
}
```

Where ListviewItemTemplate is a class consisting of two strings `Name` and `Source`